# How to tell which module a type comes from?

Tags: types, module, julia

Consider reading the following code

```
using DataFrames
using CSV

df = DataFrame()
```

How do I tell which module `DataFrame` comes from? I've tried `?DataFrame` but no useful info comes up. Here the answer is obvious of course but in large packages it isn't.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [`@which`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/stdlib/InteractiveUtils/#InteractiveUtils.@which) macro will tell you this.  It's typically used to show you which *method* gets called for a given function, but it can also show you the defining module for a given name:

```
julia> using CSV: DataFrame

julia> @which DataFrame
DataFrames
```